# startActivityForResult from dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, onactivityresult

Somewhere in my app i have a Dialog fragment, that starts an activityForResult

The problem - onActivityResult does no get called when i exit the called activity

The stranger problem - i put debug points on the onActivityResult method, it is called!!! just not when the activity ends, but BEFORE the activity is displayed fully on the screen

This is my code:

this is written in the dialog fragment

```
btnSelectContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent contactPicker = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactPickerActivity.class);
            contactPicker.putExtra(ContactData.CHECK_ALL, false);
            startActivityForResult(contactPicker, REQ_SELECT_CONTACTS);
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (data != null && data.hasExtra(ContactData.CONTACTS_DATA)) {
              data.setAction(IntentKeys.CONTACTS);
              getActivity().sendBroadcast(data);
             }

            }
```

What i am seeing is unexpected life cycle behaviour
the call stack goes like this

ImageButton click
ImageButton onClickListener called
startActivityForResult
onActivityResult of the activity it is in, of the dialog fragment it is in, of the fragment itself is called
onResume of the called activity is called
called activity does

```
Intent result = new Intent();         

    ArrayList<ContactData> resultList = contactsAdapter.items;
    Iterator<ContactData> iterResultList = resultList.iterator();

    ArrayList<ContactData> results = new ArrayList<ContactData>();
    //pass only checked contacts
    while(iterResultList.hasNext()) {

        ContactData contactData = iterResultList.next();
        if(contactData.checked) {
            results.add(contactData);
        }
    }

    result.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactData.CONTACTS_DATA, results);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();
```

and then just onResume of the dialog fragment is called instead of the expected onActivityResult

what am i doing wrong?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to start activity from fragment :

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, code);
```

to get result back in fragment :

in your parent activity (fragment call activity) :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    fragmentObject
            .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: actually it seems that if i have only 1 fragment in the activity, my way works just fine, but i have a fragment in a fragment in a fragment, and so you are correct, i do need to go through the activity, however, i do not need to do fragmentObject.onActivityResult.. it does get called anyway